# mysql sum hour where date and staff_id same, get single record instead of two

Tags: mysql, sum

it should show 1 record where date and staff id is same with sum of hours
[image]

```
SELECT s.id, s.staff_name, 
       pw.added_by as staff_id, 
       pw.date, pw.hours, 
       pw.id as worklog_id 
FROM staffs as s LEFT JOIN project_worklogs pw ON pw.added_by = s.id 
WHERE pw.date > DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY, '%d %b, %Y')
```

[image]

**updating**
i want query from last 7 days a date and less then a date

```
SELECT s.id, s.staff_name, 
       pw.added_by as staff_id, 
       pw.date, pw.hours, 
       pw.id as worklog_id 
FROM staffs as s LEFT JOIN project_worklogs pw ON pw.added_by = s.id 
WHERE pw.date > DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY, '%d %b, %Y')
and pw.date < DATE_FORMAT('2018-04-02', '%d %b, %Y')
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example, with the table structure and the query you're running.

Comment: this is my current query showing these results
.
SELECT s.id, s.staff_name, pw.added_by as staff_id, pw.date, pw.hours, pw.id as worklog_id  FROM `staffs` as s
LEFT JOIN project_worklogs pw  ON pw.added_by = s.id
WHERE pw.date > DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY, '%d %b, %Y')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do, but beware that `worklog_id` will contain just the first value encountered.

```
SELECT s.id, s.staff_name, 
       pw.added_by as staff_id, 
       pw.date, 
       SUM(pw.hours) as total_hour, 
       pw.id as worklog_id 
FROM staffs as s LEFT JOIN project_worklogs pw ON pw.added_by = s.id 
WHERE pw.date > DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY, '%d %b, %Y')
GROUP BY s.id,  pw.date
```

Comment: Please, don't use comments, open another question for this one.